# Discard longer dictionary matches which contain a nested target word

Tags: r, quanteda

I am using `tokens_lookup` to see whether some texts contain the words in my dictionary. Now I am trying to find a way to discard the matches that occur when the dictionary word is in an ordered sequence of words. To make an example, suppose that Ireland is in the dictionary. I would like to exclude the cases where, for instance, Northern Ireland is mentioned (or any fixed set of words that contains Britain). The only indirect solution that I figured out is to build another dictionary with these sets of words (e.g. Great Britain). However, this solution would not work when both Britain and Great Britain are cited. Thank you.

```
library("quanteda")

dict <- dictionary(list(IE = "Ireland"))

txt <- c(
  doc1 = "Ireland lorem ipsum",
  doc2 = "Lorem ipsum Northern Ireland",
  doc3 = "Ireland lorem ipsum Northern Ireland"
)

toks <- tokens(txt)

tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by specifying another dictionary key for "Northern Ireland", with the value also "Northern Ireland".  If you use the argument `nested_scope = "dictionary"` in `tokens_lookup()`, then this will match the longer phrase first and only once, separating "Ireland" from "Northern Ireland".  By using the same key as the value, you replace it like for like (with the side benefit of now having these two tokens, "Northern" and "Ireland", combined a single token.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

dict <- dictionary(list(IE = "Ireland", "Northern Ireland" = "Northern Ireland"))

txt <- c(
  doc1 = "Ireland lorem ipsum",
  doc2 = "Lorem ipsum Northern Ireland",
  doc3 = "Ireland lorem ipsum Northern Ireland"
)

toks <- tokens(txt)

tokens_lookup(toks,
  dictionary = dict, exclusive = FALSE,
  nested_scope = "dictionary", capkeys = FALSE
)
## Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
## doc1 :
## [1] "IE"    "lorem" "ipsum"
## 
## doc2 :
## [1] "Lorem"            "ipsum"            "Northern Ireland"
## 
## doc3 :
## [1] "IE"               "lorem"            "ipsum"            "Northern Ireland"
```

Here I used `exclusive = FALSE` for illustration purposes, so you could see what got looked up and replaced.  You can remove that and the `capkeys` argument when you run it.

If you want to discard the "Northern Ireland" tokens, just use

```r
tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = dict, nested_scope = "dictionary") %>%
  tokens_remove("Northern Ireland")
## Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
## doc1 :
## [1] "IE"
## 
## doc2 :
## character(0)
## 
## doc3 :
## [1] "IE"
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect! A quick follow up: I was also using `kwic` to store the matched keys; do you know any way to apply the same logic to it?

Comment: You'd need to be more specific here, since I'm not sure of that exactly use case. Maybe a new question?

Comment: I can open a new question but just to give you an idea I was using `test <- kwic(toks, pattern = dict)`

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.