# Create keyword column with dictionary discarding longer matches

Tags: r, quanteda

I am using `tokens_lookup` to see whether some texts contain the words in my dictionary discarding matches included in some pattern of words with `nested_scope = "dictionary"`, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68360533/discard-longer-dictionary-matches-which-contain-a-nested-target-word). The idea is to discard longer dictionary matches which contain a nested target word (e.g. include Ireland but not Northern Ireland).

Now I'd like to:

(1) create a dummy variable indicating whether the text contains the words in the dictionary. I managed to do it with the code below but I don't understand why I have to write IE as lowercase in `as.logical`.

```
df <- structure(list(num = c(2345, 3564, 3636), text = c("Ireland lorem ipsum", "Lorem ipsum Northern 
Ireland", "Ireland lorem ipsum Northern Ireland")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


dict <- dictionary(list(IE = "Ireland", "Northern Ireland" = "Northern Ireland"), 
                   tolower = F)
corpus <- corpus(df, text_field = "text")
toks <- tokens(corpus)
dfm <- tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = dict, nested_scope = "dictionary", case_insensitive = F) %>%
  tokens_remove("Northern Ireland") %>% 
  dfm()
df$contains <- as.logical(dfm[, "ie"], case_insensitive = FALSE)
```

(2) Store the matches in another column by using `kwic`. Is there a way to exclude a dictionary key in kwic (Northern Ireland in the example)? In my attempt I get a keyword column that contains both Ireland and Norther Irland matches. (I don't know if it makes any difference, but in my full dataset I have multiple matches per row). Thank you.

```
words <- kwic(toks, pattern = dict, case_insensitive = FALSE)
df$docname = dfm@Dimnames[["docs"]]
df_keywords <- merge(df, words[ , c("keyword")], by = 'docname', all.x = T)
df_keywords <- df_keywords %>% group_by(docname, num) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(docname, num, text, contains), 
              values_from = keyword, names_from = n, names_prefix = 'keyword')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```r
df <- structure(list(
  num = c(2345, 3564, 3636),
  text = c("Ireland lorem ipsum", "Lorem ipsum Northern
Ireland", "Ireland lorem ipsum Northern Ireland")
),
row.names = c(NA, -3L),
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1.0
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
dict <- dictionary(list(IE = "Ireland", "Northern Ireland" = "Northern Ireland"),
  tolower = FALSE
)
corpus <- corpus(df, text_field = "text", docid_field = "num")
toks <- tokens(corpus)
```

Here you need to flip the `tolower = FALSE` in the `dfm()` call, or it will lowercase the keys from the `tokens_lookup()`.

```r
dfmat <- tokens_lookup(toks, dict, nested_scope = "dictionary", case_insensitive = FALSE) %>%
  dfm(tolower = FALSE)
dfmat
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 2 features (33.33% sparse) and 0 docvars.
##       features
## docs   IE Northern Ireland
##   2345  1                0
##   3564  0                1
##   3636  1                1

df$contains_Ireland <- as.logical(dfmat[, "IE"])
df
## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##     num text                                   contains_Ireland
##   <dbl> <chr>                                  <lgl>           
## 1  2345 "Ireland lorem ipsum"                  TRUE            
## 2  3564 "Lorem ipsum Northern\nIreland"        FALSE           
## 3  3636 "Ireland lorem ipsum Northern Ireland" TRUE
```

For part 2, we don't have the match nesting implemented for `kwic()`.  But you can search for "Ireland" and then exclude the matches where "Northern" came before?

```r
words <- kwic(toks, pattern = "Ireland", case_insensitive = FALSE, window = 2) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  # removes the matches on IE value "Ireland" nested withing "Northern Ireland"
  dplyr::filter(!stringr::str_detect(pre, "Northern$")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(num = as.numeric(docname))
words
##   docname from to pre keyword        post pattern  num
## 1    2345    1  1     Ireland lorem ipsum Ireland 2345
## 2    3636    1  1     Ireland lorem ipsum Ireland 3636

dplyr::full_join(df, words, by = "num")
## # A tibble: 3 × 10
##     num text    contains_Ireland docname  from    to pre   keyword post  pattern
##   <dbl> <chr>   <lgl>            <chr>   <int> <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <fct>  
## 1  2345 "Irela… TRUE             2345        1     1 ""    Ireland lore… Ireland
## 2  3564 "Lorem… FALSE            <NA>       NA    NA  <NA> <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   
## 3  3636 "Irela… TRUE             3636        1     1 ""    Ireland lore… Ireland
```

Comment: Just one doubt about part 2: if in my full dataset I have several cases of this issue, should I solve them one by one (i.e. using a series of `pattern`)? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes that would be best.